# .timeout() function in simpy: how does it work?

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

I have been trying to write a simulation script where entities go though a process of events. Each event is independent for each entity and this is where I want to implement a timeout function for the entity that is present in that event.

I don't know if I have understood the documentation correctly but in all the examples I have seen pauses the environment aka env.timeout(). I am wondering how timeout works and how I could apply a timeout for a specific entity?

Maybe I am not even using the right library or have to combine with different ones, so I am open to suggestions! Please take a look at my code below :)

FYI pretty new to programming

```
import simpy


class G:
    # The properties for the system
    cycle_time = 10
    interrupt_time = 3
    load_time = 4


class Delivery:
    def __init__(self, d_id):
        self.id = d_id


class System:
    def __init__(self):
        self.env = simpy.Environment()
        self.load_station = simpy.Resource(self.env, capacity=1)
        self.active_time = simpy.Container(self.env, init=G.cycle_time, capacity=G.cycle_time)
        self.new_cycle = self.env.process(self.new_cycle())

    def new_cycle(self):
        while True:
            if self.active_time.level <= 10:
                
"""
                here I want the timeout to only have effect on the delivery trucks that are
                in the process of traveling on the road but not loading the trucks, like a red
                light.
"""
                yield self.env.timeout(G.interrupt_time)

                next_cycle = yield self.active_time.put(G.interrupt_time)

                self.env.process(next_cycle)

    def load(self):
        with self.load_station.request() as req:
            yield req
"""
                here I want the timeout to only have effect on the delivery truck that is
                loading are
"""
            yield self.env.timeout(G.load_time)
    """
    there are several more functions that describe the system but I hope this will suffice
    """
```

Comment: You need to make a process that models all the steps/tasks that a entity needs to do.  Then you need to start this process once per entity.  You can think of it as a thread per entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick example of modeling a entity with multiple step process

The basic process is a entity travels to a warehouse and gets loaded by one of two loading processes.

The first process (the travel process) has simple logic to assign the entity to its next task (one of the two loading tasks).

This is a common way to chain tasks together.  I think it makes maintenance a lot easier then trying to maintain one massive control process with a lot of nested if statements.  This way, the logic is simply, "I'm know I'm in this task, therefore, what is the next step?"  Of course, your entity can also have attributes that track "state", that can be used in the selection of the next task.

```
"""
simple entity flow of a entity

enity has a common first task, but 
chooses which second task it does

scenario being model is:
entity travels to a warehouse.
When arries entity  is either 
unloaded quickly,
or unloaded slowly

unloading requires a loader resource

Programer: Michael R. Gibbs
"""

import simpy
import random

class Entity():
    """
    Simple entity, has a id
    """

    next_id:int = 1

    def __init__(self):

        self.id = self.__class__.next_id
        self.__class__.next_id += 1

def task_1_travel(env, entity, loader_pool):
    """
    models the time a entity takes to get to a warehouse

    This process will also select the entitys next task
    """

    print(f'{env.now:.2f} entity {entity.id} has started traveling')

    # travel time
    yield env.timeout(random.triangular(1, 10, 5))

    print(f'{env.now:.2f} entity {entity.id} has finished traveling')

    # pick next task
    # note we do not yield here
    # so this task can end
    if random.random() < 0.3:
        env.process(task_2_load_slow(env, entity, loader_pool))
    else:
        env.process(task_2_load_fast(env, entity, loader_pool))


def task_2_load_slow(env, entity, loader_pool):
    """
    slow loading

    """

    print(f'{env.now:.2f} entity {entity.id} has queued for slow loader')

    with loader_pool.request() as req:
        yield req

        print(f'{env.now:.2f} entity {entity.id} has seized a slow loader')


        yield env.timeout(random.triangular(5,15, 10))

    print(f'{env.now:.2f} entity {entity.id} has finished loading and released a slow loader')


def task_2_load_fast(env, entity, loader_pool):
    """
    fast loading

    """

    print(f'{env.now:.2f} entity {entity.id} has queued for fast loader')

    with loader_pool.request() as req:
        yield req

        print(f'{env.now:.2f} entity {entity.id} has seized a fast loader')


        yield env.timeout(random.triangular(1, 10, 4))

    print(f'{env.now:.2f} entity {entity.id} has finished loading and released a fast loader')


def gen_entites(env, loader_pool):
    """
    Endless loop to generate entites
    and to assign them to their first task
    """

    while True:
        
        yield env.timeout(random.triangular(1, 8, 2))

        entity = Entity()
        # note no yield here since we are not waiting on
        # the entity to finish its task before next entity start
        # Also not we are starting a new process for each entity
        env.process(task_1_travel(env, entity, loader_pool))



# boot up
env = simpy.Environment()
loader_pool = simpy.Resource(env,2)

env.process(gen_entites(env, loader_pool))

env.run(100)
```

Comment: I hope I understand this correctly. I initially wondered if env.timeout() was separate for each entity. So for example: (just for scenarios sake) if a drug cartel transports illegal product from A to B. If delivery 1 finish loading and starts travel time but in the middle gets stopped by police and warns the other trucks to not start travel time until IT(1st truck) starts rolling again. In this case the 2nd truck can finish loading but can't start travel until the first truck has finished that timeout on the road. So I guess env.timeout() only effects the truck that is active in that process?

Comment: In this example each process with its entity is independent of all the other processes.  So if you kill one process, only that one entity is affected.  Note that processes can comminate with each other.  So you could have a cop process that "interrupts" and shipment process, and that interrupted process then raises a flag that affects the behavior of the other shipments.  The school bell example shows one way processes can communicate.